# Add markers to wherever the user taps on Google Maps iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have a brand new iOS Google Maps app. I would like to get the coordinates (latitude and longitude) of wherever the user "taps", and display a marker at those coordinates. Here's the code I need to work with (it came from integrating Google Maps):

```
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
```

My plan:
1. Store location of tap (latitude and longitude) in two variables
2. Insert into the method above.

That should work, correct? Or should I use a for loop for it, so its continuously watching for taps?

Also how could I make the markers draggable? Which is surely more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delegate method below to know when user tap on your GMSMapView.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
```

If you want to make your marker draggable, just set:
`marker.draggable = YES;`

Comment: I am unable to include this in the implementation file. When I do the next defined method throws an error saying "Expected method body".